# How to remove \n \t from Scrapy output but leave HTML tags there

Tags: scrapy

I am newbie to Scrapy and Python.

Nevertheless I've created a spider that extracts required information for me.
The only issue is that I am unable to remove \n \t symbols from output and leave, at the same time, html tags at its places.

For example:

My current output is:

```
{'specification': ['<div class="col-lg-5 model__spec">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul class="offer__spec">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<li class="offer__spec-elem">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="offer__spec-elem--left muted">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span>Бренд</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class="offer__spec-elem--right">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<span>Huawei</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div> ...']}
```

Desired output:

```
{'specification': ['<div class="col-lg-5 model__spec"><ul class="offer__spec"><li class="offer__spec-elem"><div class="offer__spec-elem--left muted"><span>Бренд</span></div><div class="offer__spec-elem--right"><span>Huawei</span></div> ...']}
```

My script:

```
import scrapy
```

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

```
name = "quotes"

start_urls = [

        'https://boo.ua/catalog/smartfony/huawei-p30-lite-4-128gb--mar-lx1a-/',
        'https://boo.ua/catalog/smartfony/huawei-p20-2018-4-128gb-black-eml-l29/',
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.xpath('descendant::div[@class="col-lg-5 model__spec"]'):
        yield {
            'specification': quote.getall()
        }
```

I've tried to use 'normalize-space' but it removed \t \n along with all html tags an I got raw text

```
    def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.xpath('normalize-space(descendant::div[@class="col-lg-5 model__spec"])'):
        yield {
            'specification': quote.getall()
        }
```

Output:

```
{'specification': ['Бренд Huawei Емкость аккумулятора 3340 мАч Диагональ экрана 6.1 Процессор HiSilicon Kirin 710 Количество ядер процессора 8 Частота процессора 2.2 ГГц Встроенная память 128 ГБ Оперативная память 4 ГБ Беспроводные коммуникации 3G, 4G(LTE), Bluetooth, GPS, NFC, Wi-Fi, ГЛОНАСС Стандарт связи 3G (WCDMA/UMTS), 4G (LTE), GSM Все характеристики']}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "quotes"

    start_urls = [

        'https://boo.ua/catalog/smartfony/huawei-p30-lite-4-128gb--mar-lx1a-/',
        'https://boo.ua/catalog/smartfony/huawei-p20-2018-4-128gb-black-eml-l29/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath('(descendant::div[@class="col-lg-5 model__spec"])'):
            quote = quote.getall()
            quote = [i.replace("\t", "").replace("\n", "") for i in quote]
            yield {
                'specification': quote
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with strip():

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.xpath('descendant::div[@class="col-lg-5 model__spec"]'):
        yield {
            'specification': quote.get().strip()
        }
```